# How do I print a menu with links generated by my custom module?

Tags: 7, routes

If I use

```
theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('main-menu'),
'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'main-menu')) ));
```

It will print the links in my Main Menu. I need to print the links that are created by my custom module, but I do not know what the system menu name is.

For instance:

```
 //hook_menu
 function custom_menu() {

     //admin page
     $items['admin/custom'] = array(
     'title' => t('Custom Admin Page'),
     'description' => t('Manage Custom Module'),
     'page callback' => 'custom_admin_page',
     'access arguments' => array('access toolbar'),
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     );

     //add event
     $items['admin/custom/add'] = array(
     'title' => t('Add Custom'),
     'decription' => t('Add custom'),
     'page callback' => 'custom_add',
     'access arguments' => array('add custom'),
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     'file' => 'custom_add.inc',
     'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/includes',
     );
```

The page 'admin/custom' automatically goes into my administration menu, and the page 'admin/custom/add' is seen under the admin/custom link when viewing all of the links in the administration menu, but I want to print that menu (admin/custom) on the 'admin/custom' page so that I can see the link 'admin/custom/add'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menus and paths are slightly different things...in `hook_menu()` you're defining paths that can be consumed; menus create the links to those paths - the two concepts aren't necessarily related (a path can exist without a menu link).

You can assign a particular router path to a menu using the `menu_name` property in your `hook_menu()` items, but that menu needs to exist already.

Fortunately Drupal provides a method for adding links to the top of a page through `hook_menu()`, and you only need to change one line:

```
$items['admin/custom/add'] = array(
  'title' => t('Add Custom'),
  'decription' => t('Add custom'),
  'page callback' => 'custom_add',
  'access arguments' => array('add custom'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION, // <-- This one changed
  'file' => 'custom_add.inc',
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/includes',
);
```

That will put a link to 'Add Custom' at the top of the 'admin/custom' page; if you're using the Seven theme for administration it'll look like the 'Add Content' link on the content admin page:

[image]

Comment: that worked! That added the link to the 'admin/custom' page! I can't ask for too much at this point, but just wondered if I can change the icon. The plus sign looks great for 'add', but the next one will be edit.

Comment: The icon comes from CSS so you could probably just target the 2nd link (`.action-links li:eq(2) a { background-image: /path/to/img) }`)

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wasn't sure if it was a directive that could be changed via Drupal hook. Thanks

Comment: Any way to order the links?

Comment: Sure, you can add a `weight` integer property to menu items, lower items appear first

Answer (score -1):

You should see [hook_menu path added to navigation menu not showing up](https://drupal.org/node/1161362).

You need to change the following line of code.

```
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
```